# How to make components not visible in react

Tags: reactjs

So I have this problem where I want to exclude a component in react. I already put the component that I want to exclude but it is still displaying.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Navbar />
          <Sidebar />

          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/note" element={<Notelist />} />
            <Route path="/note/create" element={<Create />} />
            <Route path="/note/:id" element={<Notedetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />}></Route>
        </Routes>


      </div>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

NotFound.js

```
const NotFound = () => {
    return (
        <div className="page-wrap d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <span className="display-1 d-block">404</span>
                        <div className="mb-4 lead">The page you are looking for was not found.</div>
                        <Link to='/'>Back to Home</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NotFound;
```

Now when I type anything in the URL this will be displayed:

[image: Notfound]

but this is not what I want. Sidebar and Nav bar should not be visible.
It should be like this:

[image: Correct not found]

I'm just new to reactjs so bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the  `<Sidebar />` to be rendered conditionally like in some pages it should be visible and other pages not. Then in that case you can adopt:

- Best way to handle this is not to put `<SideBar/>` into main application file i.e App.js. Keep this at page level.
- Other way is make `<SideBar/>` component conditional like put a regex for path match and then render your component [which is not a good practice]
- if you go by `<Switch/>`  , `<BrowserRouter/>` , `<Route/>` then check the below implementation:

**note : you need to place 404 route before main app route to match first.**

---

```
const Main = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/404" exact render={() => <div>404</div>} />
          <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

---

For App.js/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />

      <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/note" element={<Notelist />} />
        <Redirect to="/404" />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```